# Xcode & Gitlab : An unknown error occurred when cloning an existing project

Tags: ios, xcode, git, version-control, gitlab

I have been trying to clone a project using XCode. And I keep on getting this error.

```
An unknown error occurred.
invalid Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8" (-1)
```

My link looks something like this.

http://192.123.123.123:30000/ABC/ios/my-example-app

[image]

Could you tell me what causes this problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link looks incorrect. It should be formatted similar to one of the following:

```
http://<IP_ADDR>/<GROUP_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>.git
```

or

```
git@<IP_ADDR>:<GROUP_NAME>/<PROJECT_NAME>.git
```

It seems that your link could be fixed by appending ".git" to the end of the string, i.e.

```
http://192.123.123.123:30000/ABC/ios/my-example-app.git
```